# Proving that there is no unique factorisation into S-primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, normed-spaces, prime-factorization

Let $S = \{a+b*\surd(−5) : a, b ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$. $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. We can add and multiply elements of $S$ to get another element of $S$ and all the normal rules (as for $\mathbb{Z}$) hold. We can now define factorizations, divisibility, etc, in $S$ in the same way as for $\mathbb{Z}$. The units of $S$ are the elements $u$ such that there exists an element $v$ so
that $uv = 1$. A factorisation $t = xy$ in $S$ is called trivial if either $x$ or $y$ is a unit.
An element $t \in S$ is called an S-prime if it has no non-trivial factorisations. We define the norm of an element $s = a + b√(−5)$ to be $N(s) = a^2 + 5b^2(= ss^*)$.

1. Show that there are no elements in $S$ of norm 2 or 3
2. By considering factorisations of 6 and using norms, show that $S$ does not
   have unique factorisation into S-primes

In (1) I can see that no $a$ or $b$ exist such that $a^2 + 5b^2 = 2$ and $a^2 + 5b^2=3$. However, I am not sure how to prove it more explicitly other than do this:

$a^2+5b^2=(a+b)^2 - 2ab + 4b^2$ has to be divisible by $2$ for the norm to exist. Clearly $2|2ab$ and $2|4b^2$ and so any linear combination will divide 2. But we then expect $2|(a+b)^2$ $\rightarrow$ $(a+b)|\surd(2)$ which is impossible since $a$ and $b$ are integers. Similarly, for the norm of $3$ we have that $3|(a+b)^2$ which is again not the case since $a$ and $b$ are integers.

In (2) I am not sure what approach to use. Following the hint I did that $N(6) = N(2*3) = N(2) * N(3)$

But then if we consider $N(2)$ which implies that $t = a+b\surd(-5) = 2$ we have that there are multiple values of $a$ and $b$ that give $t$. For instance, $a=2$ and $b=0$ or $a=7$ and $b=-5$ and so on. I cannot see at the moment if this helps or not as I do not even know where to start.
I would appreciate any advise!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, your proof for (1) is not correct. How did you "deduce" that "$(a+b)\mid\sqrt{2}$"? There are at least two issues with that. First, you can't switch the two numbers in a divisibility statement: $a\mid b$ does **not** imply that $b\mid a$ (so these two statements are not equivalent). Quick counterexample: $2\mid6$, but $6\nmid2$. Second, taking the square root of a divisibility statement (relation) is a highly questionable operation, exactly because it may introduce non-integers into a relation that was originally defined for integers only, so you end up with a meaningless statement.

But that proof can be done much easier. Let's say $a^2+5b^2=2$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers. If $b\neq0$, then $b^2\ge1$ and $a^2+5b^2\ge5$, so it can't be equal $2$. Therefore, $b$ has to be $0$. With $b=0$, we get $a^2=2$, which is impossible for integer $a$.

In the second part, you seem to be confused with **inputs** and **outputs** of the norm function. $N(2)$ does **not** mean the norm of a number being equal to $2$. On the contrary, here you're given a number, which is $s=2=2+0\sqrt{-5}$ (so $a=2$ and $b=0$), and then $N(2)$ is the norm of this number specifically, which is $N(2)=2^2+5\cdot0^2=4$.

The key to the second question is to find two different factorizations of $6$ into $S$-primes. You will have to prove that the numbers involved are indeed $S$-primes, and you will have to use part (1) for that. You already have one factorization $6=2\cdot3$. You need to show that both $2$ and $3$ are $S$-primes. For example, for $2$, you can start by observing that $N(2)=4$. If $2=pq$, a product of two non-units, then $N(p)N(q)=N(2)=4$, where neither norm can be $1$ (because they are non-units). Then the only remaining way to factor $4$ is $4=2\cdot2$, so $N(p)=2$ and $N(q)=2$ — but we already showed that this is impossible. Similarly for $3$.

This gives you one factorization of $6$ into $S$-primes. The other one is $6=\left(1+\sqrt{-5}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{-5}\right)$.

Comment: When we say that $N(p) = 2$ and $N(q) = 2$ is impossible by the 1st part, how does it show that 2 is S-prime?

Comment: @Blondie: Because we're looking for non-trivial factorizations, other than $2=1\cdot2$ (which isn't much of a factorization is it?). If we show that it's impossible to factor $2$ in any other way, we'll have shown that $2$ is $S$-prime.The key is $N(pq)=N(p)N(q)$, where all norms are non-negative integers. So if $pq=2$, then $N(p)N(q)=N(pq)=N(2)=4$. In other words, $N(p)N(q)=4$ is a factorization of $4$ into two positive integers. How can we factor $4$? Only as $4=1\cdot4$ or $4=2\cdot2$. The first option doesn't really count because $N(p)=1$ implies $p=1$ producing $2=1\cdot2$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Having proved that the factorisation is not unique for 6, how can I prove it that it is not unique in general for S?

Comment: @Blondie: That's it -- this is the proof. Unique factorization property means that **each element** has a unique factorization. If at least one element has multiple factorizations, that already means that the property doesn't hold. (We're not trying to show that all elements have multiple factorizations -- that's simply not true. Many elements still have have a unique factorization, but **not all**, and that's what we needed to demonstrate, and that's exactly what we achieved by showing two different factorizations for $6$.)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain this! I now understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you can use the fact that $a^2$ and $5b^2$ are both positive. For there to be any chance of a solution, $b$ must be $0$ (otherwise $a^2+5b^2\ge 5$). It's then clear that no values of $a$ work.

For 2, the idea is to find a different factorisation of $6$ other than $2\times 3$. Norms come in because you still need to check that the elements in this factorisation are $S$-primes – there are primes of $\mathbb Z$ which are not primes in $S$.

For example, $2$ is irreducible. Indeed, if $ab = 2$, then $N(ab) = N(a)N(b) = 4$. This means that either

- $N(a)$ or $N(b)$ is $1$, so $a$ or $b$ is a unit, or
- $N(a) = 2$, which is impossible by part 1.

Comment: The formatting in the previous comment went wrong & I somehow cannot edit it. So I am reposting the comment so that it is easier to read :) Thank you for your reply! Following your example I did: $N(ab) = N(a) * N(b) = 6$. Hence, we either have that $N(a) = 2$ and $N(b) = 3$ or vice versa which is impossible since by previous part no such norms exist. Or we have that $N(a) = 6$ and $N(b) = 1$ or vice versa which implies that ether $N(a)$ or $N(b)$ is a unit and so there is no unique factorisation. However, this is the case for $6$ and I am not sure how one can generalise to prove for all $S$?

Comment: @Blondie: While it's impossible to edit a comment after a few minutes from posting it (5 minutes or so, I don't remember), you can always delete a comment.

Comment: @Blondie: As for your reasoning in this comment, note that according to the given definition of the norm, $N(6)\neq6$, but $N(6)=N(6+0\sqrt{-5})=6^2+5\cdot0^2=36$.

Comment: @Blondie to show that $S$ does not have unique factorisation, you need to find distinct primes $a,b,c,d\in S$ such that $ab = cd$. So if you can find primes $a,b\in S\setminus\{2,3\}$ such that $6 = ab = 2\times 3$, then your done. The first step is to find such $a,b$ (they exist! Think difference of two squares). Then you need to prove that $2,3,a,b$ are all prime.